# read in published Google Sheet without downloading or authenticating

Tags: r

I published a Google Sheet (via "Publish to the web") with several sheets, and I want to read them into R without downloading.

If I only had one sheet, `SheetA`, `read.csv` would do the trick. This works:

```
sheetA <- read.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQctdWKg1rPRdpaOCZhhehYdWL51AaddThDT44-JUpYHUaPpnW6j83pWtbXCRfUPeVXiMI2boSwoRZY/pub?output=csv")
```

But I have multiple sheets, so I tried `readxl` with the `output=xlsx` end to the URL. This does not work because the URL is not a valid path:

```
library(readxl)
sheetA <- read_excel("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQctdWKg1rPRdpaOCZhhehYdWL51AaddThDT44-JUpYHUaPpnW6j83pWtbXCRfUPeVXiMI2boSwoRZY/pub?output=xlsx", 
                     sheet="sheetA")
```

If there a way to read a specific sheet from a published Google Sheet that is similar to `read.csv` (no temp file)? I tried sharing the sheet (via Share, not Publish to the web) and using `googledrive::drive_get(as_id(myURL))`, but it required me to authenticate, and I don't want to do that. Maybe I'm not using `googledrive` correctly.

Comment: The file is corrupt as delivered, this has nothing to do with `read_excel`. Try downloading externally and opening manually (in Excel or Calc), the app complains about it.

Comment: Hmm, when I paste the URL (the one with `output=xlsx`) into a browser, the file downloads and opens fine in Excel for me.

Comment: When I downloaded it, the file was recognized but Excel complained that it needed fixing. I don't think it's a problem with my local Office 2016 install, but it could very well be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some luck with the `googlesheets` package.  You'd need to key the key for the sheet first, which requires authentication.  But once you have the key, as long as the sheet is public/published, you won't need to authenticate.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(googlesheets)

#list all sheets, will require authentication
my_key <- gs_ls() %>% 
  #filter to the sheet you're interested in and grab the key
  filter(sheet_title == "My Sheet Title") %>% 
  select(sheet_key)

#using the key, you can grab public/published worksheets without authentication
gs_key(my_key$sheet_key) %>%
  gs_read(ws = "Worksheet Name")
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jordo82. I see that `googlesheets` is not under active development, and `googlesheets4` is the replacement. I shared the sheet (rather than Publish to the web). To get `SheetA` without authentication: `read_sheet("1ziAFR5_QIpTlEI4-n8Uqwjox4ZIbuqIZk-TEuLa_0I0", sheet="sheetA")`